# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have defined 'title' in my component but when I import it from another component I'm getting this error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')**. Below is my code

```
export const TitleLogo = ({ title, caption, className }) => {
  return (
    <h1 className={`${className}  title-logo`}>
      <span>{caption}</span>
      {title}
    </h1>
  )
}

export const TitleSm = ({ title }) => {
  return <h1 className='titleSm'>{title}</h1>
}
export const Title = ({ title, className }) => {
  return <h1 className={`${className} title`}>{title}</h1>
}
```

I tried importing 'title' from another component but getting the  error that it's undefined. Below is my code

```
import { blogdata } from "@/assets/data/dummydata"
import Banner from "@/components/Banner"
import { Title, TitleSm } from "@/components/common/Title"
import Head from "next/head"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import React from "react"

const SinglePost = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const post = blogdata.find((post) => post.id === parseInt(id))

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{post.title}</title>
      </Head>
      <section className='post-details bg-top'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='heading-title'>
            <TitleSm title='TIPS & TRICKS / JANUARY 12, 2022' /> <br />
            <br />
            <Title title={post.title} className='title-bg' />
            <div className='img py'>
              <img src={post.cover} alt={post.title} width='100%' height='100%' className='round' />
            </div>
```

Comment: This error could be thrown because of your `blogdata.find(...)` returns `undefined` instead of your expected `post` object and you try to access the property `title` on `undefined`. So it could be that your `id` is `undefined` or it is not in your `blogdata`.

Comment: Check if your `blogData` has any item, also check if your `find` has any results? And if you are sure about the id in the query simply parse it there: `const id = parseInt(router.query)` then use it. Even I suggest to check it for emty or null values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.